# Android Studio; BottomNavigationView = null despite reorganizing code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, null, bottomnavigationview

I looked at this following example and I still have the same error message. [BottomNavigationView is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540608/bottomnavigationview-is-null)
Please not that inbetween the imports and @Override in my Java class there is other code. However, the error showcases that line 66 is the error, aka the folowing line:

```
navigationBottom.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
```

I have looked everywhere online and no solutions worked, any advice? This is one of my first projects for android studio so I am sorry if it is an obvious fix.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my java class file

```
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) // onCreate is used to start an activity. super is used to call the parent class constructor. setContentView is used to set the xml
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // setting the content view res

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.parseData); // recycler view

        arrayListOne = new ArrayList<String>(); // array list one
        arrayListTwo = new ArrayList<String>(); // array list two

        arrayLocation = new ArrayList<String>(); // date string
        arrayDate = new ArrayList<String>(); // date string
        arrayDepth = new ArrayList<String>(); // depth string
        arrayMag = new ArrayList<String>();  // mag string
        arrayLon = new ArrayList<String>(); // lon string
        arrayLatLong = new ArrayList<String>(); // lat long string

        BottomNavigationView navigationBottom = findViewById(R.id.navigationBottom); // bottom nav

        navigationBottom.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);


        new ProcessInBackground().execute();
    }
```

And here is my .xml file (bottom_navigation.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="650dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="293pt"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationBottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_bottom" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is the BottomNavigationView in activity_main.xml ?

Comment: @sdex nah I have a separate xml file called bottom_navigation.xml , its in the same layout folder as the activity_main.xml

Comment: It has to be in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Please put your `BottomNavigationView` in your MainActivity.xml, either by using the `<include>` tag, or by copying it into your MainActivity.xml. If you do not do this, it will not be inflated, and thus be null.